# WooCommerce add meta data to orders depending of product type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have function which add meta data.This working correct but the problem is when I try set different meta data for simple product and other for variable product.

When I add only:

```
// Save as custom order item metadata and display on orders and email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_csku_on_orders_and_emails', 2, 4 );
function add_csku_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $myfield = 'myfield'; // Value "my field"
    $csku    = $values['data']->get_meta( 'csku' ); // Get product "csku"

    if ( ! empty( $csku ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'csku', $csku ); // add it as custom order item metadata
        $item->add_meta_data( 'myfield', $myfield ); // add it as custom order item metadata
    }
}
```

Then this above function correctly inserts metadata to all products type in the orders API.

Now I change and need to add other metadata to simple products and others for products with variants.

```
// Save as custom order item metadata and display on orders and email notifications
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_csku_on_orders_and_emails', 2, 4 );
function add_csku_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $myfield = 'myfield'; // Value "my field"
    $csku    = $values['data']->get_meta( 'csku' ); // Get product "csku"

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'myfield', $myfield ); // add it as custom order item meta data
        $item->add_meta_data( 'csku', $csku ); // add it as custom order item meta data
    } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'csku', $csku ); // add it as custom order item meta data
    }
}
```

But I have got a problem with the second function and impossible finish checkout:

```
Error processing checkout. Please try again.
CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null in
```

Comment: `$product` is undefined in your second function.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this condition :

```
if ( 'simple' === $product->get_type() ) {
   // do things
} else {
   // another things
}
```